# Titanium Appcelerator Opens new Window and Dynamic Back button of Previous Title

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am beginning to work with Ti, and would like to know how is it possible to do the following from the code below:

1. Open a new window/view with title as "New Win"
2. Display a back button with title "My Home" (of the previous page)

This is the code that I have so far:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: "My Home",
    backgroundColor: '#bbb'
});
var b = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title:'Button',
    style:Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BORDERED
});
win.setToolbar([b]);

var nav = Ti.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
    window:win
});
var root = Ti.UI.createWindow();
root.add(nav);
root.open();

b.addEventListener({
    // open a new window with Title as "New Win"
    // with a back button, that display the previous title "My Home"
});
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: Where are you opening a new window?

Comment: You can set property in window object `backButtonTitle:My Home`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going with the right approach, only piece is missing is this:

```
      nav.open(myWindow,{animated:true});
```

here is your full code with the missing code

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
title: "My Home",
backgroundColor: '#bbb'
});
var b = Ti.UI.createButton({
title:'Button',
style:Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BORDERED
});
win.setToolbar([b]);

var nav = Ti.UI.iPhone.createNavigationGroup({
window:win
 });
var root = Ti.UI.createWindow();
root.add(nav);
root.open();

//This is your new window
var myWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
 backgroundColor:'#fff',
 title:'New Window' 
 });

// just open this new window with the navigationController you defined
 b.addEventListener('click',function(){
nav.open(myWindow,{animated:true});
});
```

With this code you will see a new window with title "New Window" and with a back button having title as "my Home".

Hope that solve your problem

====================UPDATE:=============================================================
       To solve your problem you only have to add one line i.e.
replace this

```
       var myWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
 backgroundColor:'#fff',
 title:'New Window' 
 });
```

by

```
     var myWindow = Ti.UI.createWindow({
 backgroundColor:'#fff', 
 url:'/newWindow.js'  // make sure you give the right path
 title:'New Window' 
 });
```

Comment: thanks. Can I know if I have another file called newfile.js with a window called newWindow1 and newWindow2, then how can I use the nav in this newfile.js file to open the newWindow2?